# Source maps not loaded/detected from NPM package imported into create-react-app

Tags: npm, webpack-dev-server, create-react-app, gulp-sourcemaps

I'm using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) to develop re-usable React components that can be imported individually into other projects (these projects will typically also be create-react-app projects as well). I'm using Gulp to generate the files to be consumed using a combination of gulp-sourcemaps and gulp-babel, i.e.

```
gulp.task("build:lib", function () {
let js = gulp.src([ "./src/**/*.js", "!./src/index.js"])
             .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
             .pipe(babel({presets:["react-app"]}))
             .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."}))
             .pipe(gulp.dest("lib"));
```

I can see that the .js.map files are being successfully created and that the output files have a comment in them indicating the existence of a source map, such as:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=Create.js.map
```

The issue I then have is that when the files are imported in a consuming project I am neither seeing the original source shown in browser developer tools, however when hovering over a file (in the sources tab in Chrome, within the "webpack://" tree) I see the tooltip:

> Create.js (from source map)

Therefore I can't tell whether or not I'm actually generating the source maps incorrectly or whether it's just that the webpack-dev-server configuration used by create-react-app is not serving the .js.map files (I certainly don't see them in the webpack:// tree under the sources tab in Chrome but I'm not sure whether I would expect to or not).

Any advice on whether my gulp script is wrong or on what create-react-app / webpack-dev-server should support would be much appreciated.

I've had a read through of the [documentation](https://github.com/gulp-sourcemaps/gulp-sourcemaps) for gulp-sourcemaps and tried many of the options but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found a solution to this problem myself. I converted my Gulp task to build the source maps [inline](https://github.com/gulp-sourcemaps/gulp-sourcemaps#write-inline-source-maps) (which shouldn't be a problem for the consuming application because as it is embedded as a comment it will be stripped out of the distribution file at build time).

The other thing I needed to do was to convert the `devtools` configuration in create-react-app from `cheap-module-source-map` to `eval` (unfortunately this requires [ejecting](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject)). However it does at least solve the problem.